# Send email with custom from with amazon ses for several domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, dns, amazon-ses

How can I accomplish to send email in Amazon SES with a custom email from for several domains.
For example, I have an application that is used by several clients, and we have a module to send emails. When we send an email it goes with the "amazonses.com domain", but what I want to accomplish is a custom from email for each client, each one has a different domain.

Comment: Just curious, you're clients don't actually see the "amazonses.com domain" when they receive the emails so why do you care? Just curious. Could you explain why you want to go through the effort of altering this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process for doing this is entirely specific to the current SES configuration steps so its better I provide a link thats regularly updated.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mail-from-set.html

The short summary is that you can do this by choosing a FROM option for the emails you are sending from.

**Programmatically Setting From**

The link above points how how to use the API to programmatically change the FROM value. The link below is directly to the API call for setting from but to accomplish it you'd still need to follow the manual tutorial then replace its steps with equivalent API Calls.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_SetIdentityMailFromDomain.html

Comment: But this is only for one email or for all? For example, I have more than 1000 clients, I have to do this for each client?

Comment: If you want a different from email for each of the 1000 clients they offer an API call. Since each one of your 1000 custom emails is arbitrary you'll probably have to do this programmatically using the SES api. Their is a specific command `SetIdentityMailFromDomain`. I'll add more info in an edit to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @Usman, just one question. I didn't understand this "The link below is directly to the API call for setting from but to accomplish it you'd still need to follow the manual tutorial then replace its steps with equivalent API Calls."

So, to create a new identity(each domain) i have to call this SetIdentityMailFromDomain, but wich api i have to call more?

Comment: @Luis You have to use the SetIdentityMailFromDomain call. What I meant was that it might help to know how to do it manually 1st but perhaps that might have been confusing. I was curious, why do you want to get rid of amazonses.com domain? Your customers only see that if they open the mail envelope. Seems like a lot of work for a very small problem.